# Custom menu walker - remove li tag based on class name

Tags: menus, walker

I'm using `wp_nav_menu()` to display menu items with a custom `walker`.

```
<ul>
<li id="menu-item-799" class="menu-item ... custom-theme-class"><a href="#">custom content</a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
...
</ul>
```

Now I'd like to change the `li` output depending on a class name. I use something like this:

```
function theme_function($item_output, $item, $depth, $args){    

    $output = '';       

    // Overview Menu
    if ( in_array( 'custom-theme-class', (array) $item->classes ) ) {
        $item_output = '<div class="navbar-item">'. wp_kses( $item->title, wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) ) .'</div>';
    }   

        return $item_output;  

    }
    add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'theme_function', 10, 4);
```

This simply changes

```
<li ...><a href="#">custom content</a></li>
```

to

```
<li ..."><div class="navbar-item">custom content</div></li>
```

While I wish to remove the `li` tags as well. So it becomes only

```
<div class="navbar-item">custom content</div> (without the li tags)
```

In my custom menu `walker` I used the following but it doesn't work.

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() , $id = 0) {

    ... 

    if ( in_array( 'custom-theme-class', (array) $item->classes ) ) {
        $output .= '';
    } else {
        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $data_dropdown . '>';
    }

}


function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {

    $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array)$item->classes;

    $has_children = in_array('menu-item-has-children', $classes);

    if ($has_children && $depth == 0) {            
        $output.= "</div>\n";
    }

    if ( in_array( 'custom-theme-class', (array) $item->classes ) ) {
        $output .= '';
    } else {
        $output.= "</li>\n";
    }

}
```

The `li` tags still shows when a menu is used with the `custom-theme-class` css class.

What am I missing?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have error logging on? If you're running the latest version of WP, this should be throwing an error because start_el and end_el are public functions.

Also, if you're using a custom walker, you should only use the walker and not your additional theme_function.

```
class wpseWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        if(in_array('custom-theme-class', $classes) {
            $output .= '<div class="navbar-item">' . $value;
        } else {
            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $data_dropdown . '>';
        }
    }
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        if(in_array('custom-theme-class', $classes) {
            $output .= "</div>\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "</li>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Debug` is on but I don't see any errors. Plus most tutorials about the `nav_walker` don't mention that I should use public functions, so I'm extra grateful for pointing that out to me!

Comment: I found that out the hard way recently. Most of the tutorials were written before they put "public" in place, probably when they were making updates for PHP7. It's only in recent versions that you have to add it. :)